# api for listing folders name for Recoverable Items in outlook

Tags: python, outlook, exchangewebservices

We can list all the folders in interpersonal messaging subtree using **https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders** , which contains the normal, visible folders such as Inbox, Calendar, and Sent Items.

Is there any way to list all folders for non-IPM subtree, which contains internal data, preferences, and other operational data about the mailbox.
Ex Deletions,Purge
P.S. *We can do it with following api* **https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/recoverableitemsroot/childfolders**
But for this we are using folder_id (which I don't want to use)

So if it is possible please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the non-ipm-subtree then use  https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/root however the REST api won't show you folders that don't have a Class or Subclass of IPF.Note (or are hidden eg  PR_ATTR_HIDDEN set to true). If you need access to these then you still need to look at using EWS or MAPI.

Comment: Can we call this api 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/recoverableitemsroot/childfolders' without giving 'recoverableitemsroot' in the request. I mean .. Can we fetch it using other rest api then pass it for another rest  request without making the request hardcoded.

Comment: What is your problem with specifying recoverableitemsroot (or any wellknowfolder enum) its seems you may not be understanding something correctly. /me/MailFolders is just the same as /me/MailFolders/msgfolderoot these are all wellknowfolder enumerations so aren't affect by different language local etc if that is your concern.

Comment: Thanks.which api can I use to get the recoverable items for contacts and caledars.

Comment: You need to use either EWS or MAPI, the REST API's don't support getting anything that isn't IPM.Note (or a subclass of) hopefully they will address this in the future as this isn't very useful.